# Babel cli preset config

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

Due to some certain reason I don't wish to use .babelrc file even though I'm well aware of the fact that I'm supposed to follow the rules. Anyways, for the run time I'm using the following code

```
require('babel-register')({
 babelrc: false,
 presets: [
   'stage-0',
   ['env', {
     targets: {
     node: 'current'
    }
   }]
  ],
 plugins: [
  'transform-async-to-generator',
  'syntax-async-functions'
 ]
});
require('../server/core');
```

Now I need the same config to be executed from shell. E.g.

```
babel config --out-dir
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to pass plugin/preset options via CLI arguments. https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/4161 so if you don't wish to use a `.babelrc` then there's no easy way to get args in via the CLI command.

Given that, your next best bet would be to use something like `gulp-babel` to put together your own build pipeline with programmatic arguments like `babel-register` has.

Comment: That's a headache now. Thanks though